# React Router only updating after second click

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

So, basically I have multiple nested routes like `/:platform/:account/products/:tab/:productId/summary`.
Everything works fine down to my actual single product component, but react-router stops working properly in my single product tabs.
I have a products view, with tabs (routes) , and when clicking an item, there's a popup that is the single product view, which, has 3 more tabs inside.

The child routes of my product are updating, but only on the next render cycle.

1. I'm In Summary and I click Prices: nothing happens
   (route changes to  `/:platform/:account/products/:tab/:productId/prices`)
2. I click Summary: Rendered component changes to Prices
   (route changes to  `/:platform/:account/products/:tab/:productId/summary`)
3. I click Translations: Rendered component changes to Summary
   (route changes to  `/:platform/:account/products/:tab/:productId/translations`)
4. I click Translations again: Rendered component changes to Translations
   (no route change at all)

I've been fighting with this for over 4 hours, I checked if I had any `PureComponent` in my tree, I used `withRouter` pretty much everywhere, I also checked if my product component was not updating (maybe my main view component was blocking the update), but everything seems fine, new props are correct.
I also tried using `{ pure: false }` in `connect()` but nothing helped.
I also removed this `localize` HOC just in case, but that didn't solve it.

### Version

4.2.0

### Sample code

Here is a stripped down render method from my component:

```
class ProductView extends Component {
  componentWillReceiveProps() {
    console.log("UPDATED PRODUCT TAB")
  }

  render() {
    const { match, history, translate, lang, loading, data } = this.props
    console.log(match)
    return (
      <Modal>
          <TabList>
        <TabItem>
          <NavLink
            activeClassName="active"
            to={{
              pathname: `/${match.params.platform}/${match.params.account}/products/${match.params.tab}/${match.params.productId}/summary`,
              search: location.search,
            }}
          >
            {translate("Summary")}
          </NavLink>
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem>
          <NavLink
            activeClassName="active"
            to={{
              pathname: `/${match.params.platform}/${match.params.account}/products/${match.params.tab}/${match.params.productId}/prices`,
              search: location.search,
            }}
          >
            {translate("Prices")}
          </NavLink>
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem>
          <NavLink
            activeClassName="active"
            to={{
              pathname: `/${match.params.platform}/${match.params.account}/products/${match.params.tab}/${match.params.productId}/translations`,
              search: location.search,
            }}
          >
            {translate("Translations")}
          </NavLink>
        </TabItem>
      </TabList>
          <Switch>
            <Route path="/:platform/:account/products/:tab/:id/summary" component={Summary} />
            <Route path="/:platform/:account/products/:tab/:id/prices" component={Prices} />
            <Route path="/:platform/:account/products/:tab/:id/translations" component={Translations} />
          </Switch>
      </Modal>
    )
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => (...)

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => (...)

export default withRouter(connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps,
)(localize("translate")(ProductView)))
```

The Route to get to the product Component looks like:
`<Route exact path="/:platform/:account/products/:tab/:productId/:productTab" component={ProductView} />`
Adding or removing `:productTab` makes no difference.
Inside the component with this Product Route I have other `NavLinks` for tabs and Router is working correctly.

What's weird here is that components update all the way down to my Product Route, with correct `match` props, but those child Routes, including NavLinks only update after another click.

[image: screenshot from 2017-09-20 18-44-22]

Comment: So, I tracked this down and found out it's happening because of react-modal. Any idea what's happening there? I don't see any `shouldComponentUpdated` in their code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using nested `Route` or `NavLink` (a wrapper of Route), you will need to use `Switch` (as convenience) to wrap all the modal content (or at least the part which uses Route/NavLink).

```
const location = (this. - if you component is not a function)props.location;
<Switch location={location}>
  <NavLink ... />
  <Route ... />
</Switch>
```

This will make sure that the location will be updated.

`react-modal` does not interfere on the update of user components. The  `location` that the Routes receives comes from `getChildContext()`, which only updates after the react component lifecycle. By giving to Switch the location on `render()`, the context will be the new one and it will be given to the children Routes. It will work as expected.

Comment: It works when I send location prop to switch, thanks!

Comment: Although the examples is correct, there is nothing wrong with `react-modal` and `react-router`, follow the issue on `react-modal` for more information [react-modal#499](https://github.com/reactjs/react-modal/issues/499).

Answer (score 0):

React-redux implements pure render in its `connect` function. So that might be blocking your updates

Try using `withRouter` early like this. It will stop `connect` from blocking updates coming from router.

```
export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps,
)(localize("translate")(withRouter(ProductView)))
```

Comment: Didn't work :/ I tried it all the way up to my Main Route.

Answer (score 0):

So, I managed to track it down (Not sure why I didn't try this 3 hours before...) and figured out it's due to react-modal.

There's someone else with the same issue, here's the ticket:
https://github.com/reactjs/react-modal/issues/499